# PDO Database Abstraction Layer with multiple queries in one request

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, abstract-class

I have created a **Database Abstraction Layer** over PDO to refrain from creating multiple queries around my scripts which would be pretty hard to maintain.

My DBAL is not very broad; It takes care of simple tasks such as INSERTING, UPDATING and SELECTING (with or without joining). It does not cover more advanced stuff such as selecting from multiple tables etc.

The problem that raised with my DBAL is that it is *confusing* queries when there are more of the same type in one HTTP request. For example there are three select statements in my script,  the first one works, the other two don't. I tried creating a `flush` method to clear the previously filled attributes by the query, but it's not working and I'm out of ideas. I'm not ready to get rid of my class and get back to writing queries all over - it's so easy to write them this way.

Anyway, this is how I do some queries with my class:

```
$insert_update_select = array(
    'COLUMNS' => array(
        'column_name1' => 'data_to_update_or_insert1', 
        'column_name2' => 'data_to_update_or_insert2'
    ),
    'WHERE' => array('x > y', 'y < x'),
    'ORDER' => array('ASC' => 'column_name1'),
    'LIMIT' => array(0, 5),
);

// This query works with updating, inserting and selecting
$db = new db();

$db->insert('table_name', $insert_update_select);
$db->update('table_name', $insert_update_select);
$db->select('table_name', $insert_update_select);
```

Don't ask me how to join tables; I actually forgot how my own syntax works for that, haha. (Gotta try to remember)

**Anyway, here is my class:**

```
<?php
class db
{   
    private $db_type = 'mysql';
    private $db_host = 'localhost';
    private $db_user = 'root';
    private $db_pass = '';
    private $db_name = 'imgzer';

    private $db;
    private $db_connection      = '';
    private $insert_data        = '';
    private $update_data        = '';
    private $select_data        = '';
    private $condition_data     = '';
    private $order_data         = '';
    private $limit_data         = '';   
    private $join_data          = array();
    private $query;
    private $table;

    private $return_data;
    private $affected_rows;
    private $return_id;

    // Database tables
    const USERS_TABLE   = 'imgzer_users';
    const CONFIG_TABLE  = 'imgzer_config';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db_connection = "$this->db_type:host=$this->db_host;dbname=$this->db_name";

        $this->db = new PDO($this->db_connection, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
        $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 

        unset($this->db_pass);
    }

    public function open()
    {
        if ($this->db)
        {
            return true;    
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function close()
    {
        if ($this->db->close())
        {
            return true;    
        }

        return false;
    }

    private function build_array($type, $data, $join_data = array())
    {
        if (empty($data))
        {
            return; 
        }

        $type = strtoupper($type);              

        $this->update_data = '';
        $this->select_data = '';

        $data_index  = 0;
        $data_length = sizeof($data);
        $last_row    = $data_length - 1;

        switch ($type)
        {
            case 'INSERT':

                if (!is_array($data))
                {
                    return;     
                }

                $this->insert_data = '(';

                foreach ($data as $column => $value)
                {
                    $this->insert_data .= $column . (($data_index != $last_row) ? ', ' : '');                   
                    $data_index++;
                }

                $data_index  = 0;

                $this->insert_data .= ') ';
                $this->insert_data .= 'VALUES (';

                foreach ($data as $column => $value)
                {
                    $this->insert_data .= '?' . (($data_index != $last_row) ? ', ' : '');   
                    $data_index++;
                }

                $this->insert_data .= ') ';

            break;  

            case 'UPDATE':

                $this->update_data = '';

                foreach ($data as $column => $value)
                {
                    $this->update_data .= $column . ' = ?' . (($data_index != $last_row) ? ', ' : '');
                    $data_index++;
                }

            break;

            case 'SELECT':

                if (empty($join_data))
                {
                    return; 
                }

                if (is_array($join_data))
                {
                    $from_table = array_keys($join_data['FROM']);
                    $join_table = array_keys($join_data['TABLES']);

                    $this->select_data = implode(', ', array_flip($data)) . ' FROM ' ;
                    $this->select_data .= $from_table[0] . ' ' . $join_data['FROM'][$from_table[0]] . ' ';

                    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($this->join_data); $i++)
                    {
                        $this->select_data .= $this->get_join_type($join_data['JOIN']). ' ';
                        $this->select_data .= $join_table[$i] . ' ' . $join_data['TABLES'][$join_table[$i]];
                        $this->select_data .= $this->join_data[$i]; 
                    }

                    $this->select_data = rtrim($this->select_data, ' ');
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!isset($data[0]))
                    {
                        $data = array_flip($data);
                    }

                    $this->select_data = implode(', ', $data) . ' FROM ' . $this->table . ' ';
                }

            break;
        }
    }

    private function set_join($on)
    {
        if (empty($on))
        {
            return; 
        }

        if (is_array($on))
        {
            for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($on); $i++)
            {
                $on[$i] = ' ON (' . implode(' AND ', $on[$i]) . ') ';   
            }   
        }

        $this->join_data = $on;
    }

    private function set_order($order)
    {
        if (empty($order))
        {
            return; 
        }

        $this->order_data = ' ORDER BY ';

        if (is_array($order))
        {
            $data_index = 0;
            $data_size  = sizeof($order) - 1;

            foreach ($order as $order_type => $column)
            {
                if ($order_type != 'ASC' && $order_type != 'DESC')
                {
                    throw new Exception('Order type in SQL has to be either ASC or DESC');
                    return; 
                }

                $this->order_data .= $column . ' ' . $order_type . (($data_index != $data_size) ? ', ' : ''); 
                $data_index++;
            }

            return;
        }

        $this->order_data .= $order;
    }

    private function set_limit($limit)
    {
        if (empty($limit))
        {
            return; 
        }

        if (sizeof($limit) > 2)
        {
            return; 
        }

        if (sizeof($limit) == 1)
        {
            $limit = array(0, $limit[0]);   
        }

        if (is_array($limit))
        {
            $limit = implode(', ', $limit); 
        }

        $this->limit_data = " LIMIT {$limit}";
    }

    private function set_where($condition)
    {
        if (empty($condition))
        {
            return; 
        }

        if (is_array($condition))
        {
            $condition = implode(' AND ', $condition);  
        }

        $this->condition_data = " WHERE $condition";
    }

    public function in_set($where_ary)
    {
        $where_str = implode(', ', $where_ary); 
        $where_str = substr($where_str, 0, -2);

        $where_str = 'IN (' . $where_str . ')';

        return $where_str;
    }

    /*
    * Example usage:
    * $insert_ary = array('col_1' => 'col_data_1', 'col_2' => 'col_data_2');
    * $condition_ary = array('col_1 > 5', 'col_2 <> 10');
    * $order_ary = array('ASC' => 'col_1', 'DESC' => 'col_2');
    * $limit = array($start = 0, $limit = 5);
    * $instance->insert('my_table', $insert_ary, $condition_ary, $order_ary, $limit);
    */
    public function insert($table, $data, $return_id = false)
    {
        $data = $this->data_abstract($data);

        // Prepare the arrays
        $this->build_array('INSERT', $data['COLUMNS']);
        $this->set_where($data['WHERE']);
        $this->set_order($data['ORDER']);
        $this->set_limit($data['LIMIT']);

        $sql = 'INSERT INTO ' . $table . ' ';
        $sql .= $this->insert_data;
        $sql .= $this->condition_data;
        $sql .= $this->order_data;
        $sql .= $this->limit_data;

        $this->query = $this->db->prepare($sql);

        $param_index = 1;

        foreach ($data['COLUMNS'] as $column => &$value)
        {           
            $this->query->bindParam($param_index, $value);  
            $param_index++;
        }

        $this->query->execute();

        if ($return_id)
        {
            $this->return_id = $this->query->last_insert_id();
        }
        else
        {
            $this->affected_rows = $this->query->rowCount();
        }
    }

    public function update($table, $data, $return_id = false)
    {
        $data = $this->data_abstract($data);

        // Prepare the arrays
        $this->build_array('UPDATE', $data['COLUMNS']);
        $this->set_where($data['WHERE']);
        $this->set_order($data['ORDER']);
        $this->set_limit($data['LIMIT']);

        $sql = 'UPDATE ' . $table . ' SET ';
        $sql .= $this->update_data;
        $sql .= $this->condition_data;
        $sql .= $this->order_data;
        $sql .= $this->limit_data;

        $this->query = $this->db->prepare($sql);

        $param_index = 1;

        foreach ($data['COLUMNS'] as $column => &$value)
        {           
            $this->query->bindParam($param_index, $value);  
            $param_index++;
        }

        $this->query->execute();

        if ($return_data)
        {
            $this->return_id = $this->query->last_insert_id();
        }
        else
        {
            $this->affected_rows = $this->query->rowCount();
        }
    }

    /*
    * Joining example:
    * $join_data = array(
    *   'TABLES'    => array('table_2' => 't2', 'table_3' => 't3'),
    *   'JOIN'      => 'LEFT',
    *   'ON'        => array(
    *                   array('colx > 15', 'coly < 20'),
    *                   array('fieldx > 15', 'fieldy < 20')
    *               ),
    *);
    */
    public function select($table, $data, $join = false, $fetch_type = 'assoc')
    {       
        $data = $this->data_abstract($data);

        if ($join)
        {
            if (!is_array($table))
            {
                throw new Exception('Table has to be associated with a short index');
                return; 
            }

            $this->set_join($join['ON']);
            $table = array_merge(array('FROM' => $table), $join);
        }

        // Globalize table name if not joins are used
        $this->table = $table;

        // Prepare the arrays
        $this->build_array('SELECT', $data['COLUMNS'], $table);
        $this->set_where($data['WHERE']);
        $this->set_order($data['ORDER']);
        $this->set_limit($data['LIMIT']);

        $sql = 'SELECT ';
        $sql .= $this->select_data;
        $sql .= $this->condition_data;
        $sql .= $this->order_data;
        $sql .= $this->limit_data;

        $this->query = $this->db->prepare($sql);                    
        $result = $this->query->execute();

        $fetch_type     = ($fetch_type == 'assoc') ? PDO::FETCH_ASSOC : PDO::FETCH_NUM;
        $fetched_data   = $this->query->fetchAll($fetch_type);
        $data_result    = $fetched_data;

        if (sizeof($fetched_data) == 1)
        {
            $data_result = $fetched_data[0];
        }

        $this->return_data = $data_result;

        // Clear the result
        //$this->query->closeCursor();
    }

    public function fetch()
    {
        return $this->return_data;
    }

    public function affected_rows()
    {
        return $this->affected_rows;
    }

    private function data_abstract($data)
    {
        $abstract_ary = array('COLUMNS' => '', 'WHERE' => '', 'ORDER' => '', 'LIMIT' => 0);
        return array_merge($abstract_ary, $data);   
    }

    private function get_join_type($type)
    {
        switch ($type)
        {
            default:
            case 'LEFT':
                return 'LEFT JOIN';
            break;
            case 'RIGHT':
                return 'RIGHT JOIN';
            break;  
            case 'INNER':
                return 'INNER JOIN';
            break;
            case 'NORMAL':
            case 'JOIN':
                return 'JOIN';
            break;  
        }
    }

    private function flush()
    {
        unset($this->query, $this->insert_data, $this->update_data, $this->select_data);
    }
}

$db = new db();
?>
```

What's wrong with it (could be a lot) and how do I actually make it work efficiently?

Comment: There's too much code there. Can you select just the problematic part?

Comment: I can't define which part is problematic? I guess the `select` method would be the place to start with, since it's not supporting multiple *returns* for one HTTP request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make it stateful.

Even without looking at the code I'll tell you what's the problem: get rid of `$this->stmt` variable.
For some reason, all the DBAL writers have strong inclination to such a variable... introducing state to their class and thus making it unusable.

All the method calls have to be *atomic*, each performing all the necessary operations and returning all the requested data. While saving nothing in the class variables. As simple as that. In such a rare case when PDOStatement object have to be used further - return this very object, don't save it inside. Otherwise just return the requested data.

I wold also advise to get rid of your whole DBAL, as it's written out of good intentions but I can tell for sure that implementation turns out to be less helpful but it actually makes your code worse in many aspects - readability, flexibility, maintainability. In pursue for the fictional usability, you are saving yourself only a word or two from SQL, but making whole application code unreliable.

You won't listen to me, though. Some experience in maintaining applications is required to see my point.

Comment: Please suggest an alternative method to simplify the query writing process without using an ORM or something similar. Is there a good DBAL based on PDO out there?

Comment: There is very little sense in creating a *DBAL* over PDO as PDO is already one. What's you're after is called *query builder*. You can find a lot of examples googleing for the term. though you don't actually need even this one too. I don't understand that strong desire of all the newbie programmers to get rid of precious SQL.

Comment: Accepting your answer as it includes very useful (and honest) advice. I've gotten rid of my class and start using queries all around again. I'm actually not that much of a newbie programmer, I just don't have enough time to become a professional.